# Colocar el texto y valor a un select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Muy buenas tardes amigos.

que gusto saludarlos, necesito de su ayuda, he estado trabajando en este código pero no logro colocar un texto dentro de un select. El select es cargado previamente. se hace la operación y es guardada en la base de datos, esto es para cuando se necesita actualizar la info. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    <div class="row page">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-2 align-self-center">
                        <button id="adicionarPesaje" name="adicionarPesaje" 
    type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
                        <!-- <label for="">Cantidad</label>-->
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-4" 
    id="transito" hidden readonly>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-4" 
    id="sumaTanques" readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 mt-3 insertarTanque">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" onclick="guardarDatos();" 
    class="btn btn-primary crearbatch" name="guardarBatch" 
    id="guardarBatch">Crear</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

                </div>

  //javascript
       for(k=1; k<info.length; k++){
                
                cont = k-1;
                tnque = info[k].tanque;
                cant = info[k].cantidad;
                
                $('#adicionarPesaje').click();
                $("#cmbTanque" + k + " option[value="+ tnque +"]").val(tnque);
                $('#txtCantidad'+ k).val(cant);
                
                CalcularTanque();
            }
```

Comment: Saludos. Mira aqui https://forum.jquery.com/topic/setting-selected-option-in-dropdownlist-by-the-text-not-value al  final hay ejemplo con http://jsfiddle.net/qYRr7/ solo vigila las mayúsculas y minúsculas; así mismo te comento que lo idóneo para evitar esas detalles es que uses `val` para asignar/obtener con ello usarias lo que tenga el `option` en su `value`.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que busco, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Saludos. Para que te aporten más hizo falta coloques tu código HTML donde quieres funcione (con el escenario existente); se observa `$('#txtCantidad'+ k)` igual con `"#cmbTanque"`lo que implica hay mas de un elemento en el HTML.

Comment: Tienes mucha razon, ya lo coloque. lo que sucede es que dinamicamente genero los selects y un input de cantidad, esto lo multiplico y lo muestro en un input. esto se hace tantas veces que sea necesario para el usuario. Esta informacion la guarda en la base de datos y al moment de necesitar actualizarla la leemos de la base de datos y lo debo cargar tanto en el select como en los inputs. en los inputs lo hace perfecto pero en el select no lo logro. el ejemplo que me pasaste estuvo cool. eso es lo que necesito exactamente, pero no logro hacerlo. de antemano muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

A manera de ejemplo; estuve haciendo pruebas pero no me fue posible corregir que si seleccionas directos en el `select` se pierde la posibilidad de usar el texto indicado.

```js
// Esto seria tu contenido de info que le haces un ciclo; solo coloco lo que usas en el ciclo
var info = [
{
  tanque: 'El tanque 1',
  cantidad: 1
},
{
  tanque: 'El tanque 2',
  cantidad: 2
},
{
  tanque: 'El tanque 3',
  cantidad: 3
}
];

function quitarSeleccion() {

  $("select").each(function(keySelect, valueSelect) {
    $(valueSelect).val('');
  }).promise().done(function () {
    $("select").each(function(keySelect, valueSelect) {
      $('option', valueSelect)
        .each(function () {
            $(this).attr('selected',false);
        });
    })
    });

} /* quitarSeleccion */

function ejecutarSeleccionPorTexto() {
  var strSeleccionar = $("#textoSeleccionarse").val();
  if (strSeleccionar==null) strSeleccionar='';
  //console.log(strSeleccionar);
  $("select").each(function(keySelect, valueSelect) {
    $(valueSelect).val('');
  }).promise().done(function () {
    $("select").each(function(keySelect, valueSelect) {
      $('option', valueSelect)
          .filter(function() { 
          //console.log('Opcion:' + $(this).text());
              $(this).attr('selected',false);
              return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == strSeleccionar;
          })
          .attr('selected',true);
    });
  });
 

  
}

//Creo tanto SELECT como elementos +1 hay en INFO para que veas cada uno; el primero no tendra nada seleccionado los otros sí

$(info).each(function(key, value) {
  // Creo dinamicamente  los SELECT que usare
  $(".row").append(("<select class=\"form-control col-11\">"));
/*  $(".row").html($(".row").html() + "<select class=\"form-control col-11\"></select><br />");*/
}).promise().done(function () {
/*  // Creo un elemento más
  $(".row").html($(".row").html() + "<select class=\"form-control col-11\"></select>");*/
  // Obteniendo los select
  $("select").each(function(keySelect, valueSelect) {
    // Agregando las opciones "info" a los select
    $(info).each(function(keyInfo, valueInfo) {
    //console.log(valueInfo);
     $(valueSelect).append($("<option />").val(valueInfo.cantidad).text(valueInfo.tanque));
    });
  });
});

$(function () {
  quitarSeleccion();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- En el código que pusiste no encontre un SELECT u organización de tu escenario para simularlo; te coloco como seria su uso -->

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="quitarSeleccion()">Ninguno con selección</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="ejecutarSeleccionPorTexto()">Seleccionar por texto</button>
<label>A continuación ingresa el texto que quieres sea seleccionado en todos</label><input type="text" id="textoSeleccionarse" value="El tanque 1"  />
<br /> <br />
<div class="row page">

</div>
```